# how do i convert array of one object containing many object inside to array of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array looks like below...

```
arr = [{
  Bildbearbeiter: 1,
  Bügler: 2,
  Einkäufer: 3,
  Empfänger: 4,
  Fotograf: 5,
}];
```

but I want to change it

```
arr = [{
    Bildbearbeiter: 1
  },
  {
    Bügler: 2
  },
  {
    Einkäufer: 3
  },
  {
    Empfänger: 4
  },
  {
    Fotograf: 5
  }

];
```

So that i can iterate with each object. Is there any way to solve it??

Thanks in advance

Comment: why is the object wrapped in an array, could be more than one object in the array? what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let arr = [{Bildbearbeiter: 1,Bügler: 2,Einkäufer: 3,Empfänger: 4,Fotograf: 5}];

arr = Object.entries(arr[0]).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]:v}));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Interesting approach using `.entries`. Clever.

Comment: @briosheje - Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Array.map()` and `Object.keys()`:

```js
let arr = [ { Bildbearbeiter: 1, Bügler: 2, Einkäufer: 3, Empfänger: 4, Fotograf: 5, } ];

let result = Object.keys(arr[0]).map((key)=> ({[key] : arr[0][key]}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @DevNepal Happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this by clicking on *Run code snippet* button:

```js
var arr = [{
  Bildbearbeiter: 1,
  Bügler: 2,
  Einkäufer: 3,
  Empfänger: 4,
  Fotograf: 5,
}];

var newArray = [];

for (let key in arr[0]) {
  newArray.push({
    [key]: arr[0][key]
  });
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Or try this:

```js
var arr = [{
  Bildbearbeiter: 1,
  Bügler: 2,
  Einkäufer: 3,
  Empfänger: 4,
  Fotograf: 5,
}];

var newArray = Object.keys(arr[0]).map(key => ({
  [key]: arr[0][key]
}))

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by adding all objects to the result set.

```js
var array = [{ "Bildbearbeiter": 1, "Bügler": 2, "Einkäufer": 3, "Empfänger": 4, "Fotograf": 5 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the array, loop through the `keys` of each object, and assign a brand new object holding the key and the value of the current item.

```
arr.map(i => {
    return Object.keys(i).map(k => {
       return {[k]: i[k]};
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sw3Lxm7f/